# Navigating in Windows Phone App requires additional App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently working on an Windows Phone App in Visual Studio for my Lumia 1520 with Windows Phone 10.
To navigate between the MainPage and the SecondPage, I use the code:

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
}
```

When clicking the Button in the App on my Phone, I receive the information, that:

> The task requires an additional App. Would you like to search the store for it? (Yes/No)

When I hit "Yes" I get redirected to the Store, where I receive the information:

> Your search for "ms-resource" had no results.

What kind of App is required by my phone? Is there another way to navigate between the pages without installing additional Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined **NavigateUri** for your HyperLinkButton. **Remove** that attribute and the navigation to second page should work correctly.

In more detail, your code quite likely looks like this:

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="SecondPage.xaml" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="Hello"/>
```

And your code behind as you mentioned is this:

```
            Frame.Navigate(typeof (SecondPage));
```

Now when you click the hyperlink, this happens:

[image: Search for app]

But now if you remove the NavigateUri from your XAML:

```
        <HyperlinkButton Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="Hello"/>
```

The navigation works:

[image: Second page]

This behavior is [somewhat vaguely described on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hyperlinkbutton.navigateuri):

> HyperlinkButton is a control, so it has input events such as Tapped,
>   and it's a ButtonBase subclass so it also has a Click event. You don't
>   typically specify a value for NavigateUri and also handle input events
>   that are interpreted as clicking the HyperlinkButton. The action of
>   **opening the NavigateUri in a default browser is a system action** that
>   takes place without requiring any event handling.

Comment: That totally solved the issue! Sorry for bothering, it was truly just a detail. Thanks a lot!